# Split Excel file based on other file

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

I have 2 Excel files. Looking for a solution using Office script and Power automate.

File 1: master file containing store date (column A = store, column B = product, column C to Z contains sales data).

File 2: store list with an account manager (column A = account manager, column B = store)

How can i split file 1 in multiple files (1 per account manager)?

Thanks!

Regards,
Hans

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters and return values in an Office Script to pass data to and from and Excel workbook in a Power Automate Flow. These samples may help you:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/get-table-data
- https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/combine-worksheets-into-single-workbook

Basically, your Flow that you create should look something like this:
[image: Power Automate Flow to create separate workbooks from a table in a master file]

Your Flow will run a script to get the list of manager/store list pairings in File 2. For each manager, a second script will run on File 1 that will take the stores that the account manager is responsible for (returned from the first script and sent as a parameter in the second script) in order to look for the matching rows. Then, that script will return the rows matching the store list parameter in File 1. Next, a copy of a template file will be created in your desired location, and another script will run to add the rows returned from the previous script to that new file.

Below are the scripts I created to automate this workflow, but you could do so in a variety of ways.

Get Manager and Store Pairs:

```
 function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): AccountManager[]{
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Account Manager Data");

    //gets the first table in the worksheet
    let table = worksheet.getTables()[0];


    let numRows = table.getRowCount();
    let tableValues = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
    let managerColumn = table.getColumnByName("Account Manager").getIndex();
    let storeColumn = table.getColumnByName("Store").getIndex();
    let managerMap: Map<string, string[]> = new Map();
    let managerArray: AccountManager[] = []

    //iterate through table and add manager/store pair to managerArray
    for (let i=0; i<numRows; i++){
      let managerName = ""+tableValues[i][managerColumn]
      if (!managerMap.has(managerName)){
        managerMap.set(managerName, [""+tableValues[i][storeColumn]])
      }
      else{
        managerMap.get(managerName).push("" + tableValues[i][storeColumn]);
      }
    }

    managerMap.forEach(function (value, key){
      managerArray.push({manager: key, stores: value})
    });

    return managerArray; 
}

interface AccountManager{
  manager: string
  stores: string[]
}
```

Get Store Data Script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, store: string[]): (string|boolean|number)[][] {
    let table = workbook.getWorksheet("Store Data").getTables()[0];
    let numRows = table.getRowCount();
    let tableValues = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
    let storeColumn = table.getColumnByName("Store").getIndex();
    let store_Data: (string|boolean|number)[][] = [];
    store_Data.push(table.getHeaderRowRange().getValues()[0])
    for (let j=0; j< store.length; j++){
      for (let i =0; i<numRows; i++){
        if (store[j] === tableValues[i][storeColumn].toString().trim()){
            store_Data.push(tableValues[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(store_Data)
    
    return store_Data
}
```

Add Data to Store Specific Workbooks Script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, store_Data: string[][]) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

  let table_Range =selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getResizedRange(store_Data.length-1, store_Data[0].length-1)
  table_Range.setValues(store_Data);
  let table = workbook.addTable(table_Range, true);
}
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!